# Examples of log() algorithm using arbitrary precision maths

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I'm looking to find an algorithm that I can implement in PHP to get the natural log() of an integer number using arbitrary precision maths.  I'm limited by the PHP overlay library of the GMP library (see http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php for available GMP functions in PHP.)

If you know of a generic algorithm that can be translated into PHP, that would also be a useful starting point.

PHP supports a native log() function, I know, but I want to be able to work this out using arbitrary precision.

Closely related is getting an exp() function.  If my schoolboy Maths serves me right, getting one can lead to the other.

Comment: PHP's native `log` returns a `float`. How much precision do you need? Considering your input is an `int` it can't be that big.

Comment: Hi Halcyon - the int can be part of something bigger, a rational, a complex number.  I can convert an integer to a float for sure, but this is arbitrary precision so converting down to native float and then up (as I'm currently doing,) can lose the precision

Answer (score 9):

Well you would have the Taylor series, that can be rewritten for better convergence
[image: Improved taylor series of ln: 2 sum_{k=0..+inf} 1/(2k+1) * ((y-1)/(y+1))^(2k+1)]

To transform this nice equality into an algorithm, you have to understand how a converging series work : each term is smaller and smaller. This decrease happens fast enough so that the total sum is a finite value : ln(y).

Because of nice properties of the real numbers, you may consider the sequence converging to ln(y) :

- L(1) = 2/1 * (y-1)/(y+1)
- L(2) = 2/1 * (y-1)/(y+1) + 2/3 * ( (y-1)/(y+1) )^3
- L(3) = 2/1 * (y-1)/(y+1) + 2/3 * ( (y-1)/(y+1) )^3 + 2/5 * ( (y-1)/(y+1) )^5

.. and so on.

Obviously, the algorithm to compute this sequence is easy :

```
x = (y-1)/(y+1);
z = x * x;
L = 0;
k = 0;
for(k=1; x > epsilon; k+=2)
{
    L += 2 * x / k;
    x *= z;
}
```

At some point, your x will become so small that it will not contribute to the interesting digits of L anymore, instead only modifying the much smaller digits. When these modifications start to be too insignificant for your purposes, you may stop.

Thus if you want to achieve a precision 1e^-20, set epsilon to be reasonably smaller than that, and you're good to go.

---

Don't forget to factorize within the log if you can. If it's a perfect square for example, ln(a²) = 2 ln(a)
Indeed, the series will converge faster when (y-1)/(y+1) is smaller, thus when y is smaller (or rather, closer to 1, but that should be equivalent if you're planning on using integers).

Comment: Thanks Cimbali - I am looking for an algorithm - not an equation. Although I do understand that most processor implementations these days use a Taylor series, often with a lookup table of some sort.  SO perhaps my question should be about asking for an algorithm implementing a Taylor series to achieve a log() function.

Comment: Many thanks - that worked a treat. For anyone looking for more info, see [Taylor Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)

Comment: I don't think it's obvious where this series representation comes from. It would be nice if you could add an explanation, or link to a source. A suitable source might be:  
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4519474/198422